# Scraping webpage with selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

Hi I would like to scrap what is selected in the following image:

[Image Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uazuz.jpg)

I know i could use the following code to get the text:

```
cell = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='ip_selection1233880116name']") 
print cell.text
```

But my problem is that *ip_selection1233880116name* should be dynamic, given that it changes every time as you can see from the image.

How could I do it?

Thanks a lot for your help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use contains to catch just the name presuming the numbers all all that change, for a single element you should also use `find_element` as opposed to `find_elements` :

```
find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'ip_selection') and contains(@id,'name')]")
```

You could also use starts-with and ends-with depending on the browser:

```
find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'ip_selection') and ends-with(@id,'name')]")
```

Comment: Thanks!!!! you are a great!!! I didn't know I could use contains... With that it works really well :D... thanks again!